# Hypernym for "audiobook", "podcast", "speech", etc.?

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests, hypernyms

I am looking for a short and concise term (preferably *one* word) that can be used as a hypernym for essentially everything that contains (audio) speech (e.g. audiobooks, podcasts, recorded news bulletins, recorded performances of comedians,..).

Does such a term exist? I've thought about 'speech', but that seems to be more adequate for e.g. political speeches, and not so much for audio books and the like. But maybe I'm wrong.

Comment: I think you use the term: *audio*.

Comment: I think he's looking for a word like "audio" but which excludes things like music.

Comment: *Recorded speech* seems perfect to me.  I don't think you will find a single word that is better.

Comment: Music stores call it "spoken word".

Answer (score 3):

Depending on context, you might be able to use *recordings*.

Comment: But this also would include music and/or video.

Answer (score 2):

These would normally be refered to as [media](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Media).

But if you wish to specify further, to exclude visual media such as videos, the word [audio](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/audio) is probably the best available.

> **au·di·o**  (ôd-)  n.
>
> 1. The part of television or movie equipment that has to do with sound.
> 2. The broadcasting, reception, or reproduction of sound.
> 3. Audible sound.
> 4. **A sound signal: lost the audio during the broadcast**.

Comment: Media can include silent video.  I don't think there's a good umbrella term for what the OP's asking because the examples thon gives are rather different things.  I don't really see why there should be an umbrella term.

Comment: -1 media: means and institutions for publishing and broadcasting information.

Comment: @z7sg I think strictly-speaking you are correct with your definition (after all- it comes from the word "medium"). But I would say that the word "media" has come to be used as a collective term for all electronic things such as mp3s and videos.

Answer (score 1):

"**spoken word**" is the term used by the [National Academy of Recording Arts and Sciences](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grammy_Award_for_Best_Spoken_Word_Album).